# MS Word Header/Footer problems created from OCR

Tags: microsoft-word, footers

I have a newly created word doc that I made from Adobe OCR. Needless to say I had a lot of clean up to do and I have a problem that's really killing me. The footer is fine for the first 7 pages, however the last 2 are labeled "Footer 9", so the page number stays the same. Meaning page 8 is shows up as page 9. I can't seem to delete the Footer section, it keeps coming back to the same Footer. It's like pages 8 and 9 have a link or something that I can't break.

Any ideas out there? Really frustrating...

Comment: Since you are using OCR, I assume you are working in Acrobat, not Reader. If that's the case, you could just crop the footers out of those pages before converting it to a word file.

Comment: I converted the original pdf file to Word so I could make it look a little better. The issue is the OCR and some of the formatting. I've tried to delete-->footers in the "Check for Issues" button on the File tab, but no go. arrgh....

Comment: I forgot to mention, Yes I am using Acrobat.

Comment: So the footer text is not coming from the original PDF?

Comment: Nope. Lame. I am using an old version of Acrobat - X

Comment: Have you tried selecting Link to Previous (on the Header & Footer tools tab that shows up when you're in the footer) for the page 8 footer? That should automatically make it match the previous once, which are correct.

Comment: You would get that if you have an odd page section break in page 7.

Comment: Ok, basically the footer has been copied from page 8. So, how do I just delete on footer? This footer is NOT linked to the other page.